# Не стандарный бордер для блока

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: кастомная рамка]

Всем привет, ребят, возникли трудности в вёрстке, как можно реализовать данный вид рамки?

Comment: На макете не совсем бордер, точнее совсем не бордер. Такое можно сделать при помощи svg.

Comment: А можно по подробнее?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ещё через clip-path можно сделать.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно, но svg имхо проще

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я сейчас попробую на html без clip-path - есть интересные идеи :)

Comment: @Qwertiy я сделал псевдо элементом с радиальным градиентом, но получается не точь в точь, по-этому не публикую

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я пробовал сделать рамку сверху справа и слева, потом блок с кружком и от него псевдоэлементы расходятся с градиентом, проблема только в том что как обрезать градиент в самом блоке((

Comment: @sagro111, я только заметил, что фон градиентный, а не монотонный...

Comment: @Qwertiy Да я вот сам мучаюсь) как бы с градиентом то ладно, у меня он есть, как вот вырезать)

Comment: @sagro111, на svg легко получится.

Comment: Ребят всем спасибо за помощь и за то что отозвались) Решил SVGшкой)

Answer (score 5):

Как и советовали в комментариях, я бы сам, скорее всего, использовал SVG, но в качестве некой альтернативы, покажу [вариант с использованием JS](https://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/n21rxbaw/). Хотя, как по мне, то не самый лучший вариант.

```js
const span = document.querySelector('.card .circle');
const bgPos = () => {
  let rect = span.getBoundingClientRect();
  span.style.backgroundPosition = `-${rect.left}px -${rect.top}px`;
};
bgPos();
window.addEventListener('resize', bgPos);
```

```css
body {
  background: url(https://is.gd/nyZgUK) 0 0;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 50vw;
  background: #81502c;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 20px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #81502c 0%, #f4e0a4 50%, #81502c 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #81502c 0%, #f4e0a4 50%, #81502c 100%);
}

.card::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #81502c 0%, #f4e0a4 50%, #81502c 100%) 1;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #81502c 0%, #f4e0a4 50%, #81502c 100%) 1;
}

.card .circle,
.card .circle span,
.card .circle::before,
.card .circle span::after {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.card .circle::before,
.card .circle span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: inherit;
}

.card .circle {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -6vw;
  width: 12vw;
  height: 12vw;
  padding: 1vw;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: url(https://is.gd/nyZgUK);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card .circle span {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #81502c -20%, #f4e0a4 50%, #81502c 120%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #81502c -20%, #f4e0a4 50%, #81502c 120%);
}

.card .circle::before {
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card .circle span::after {
  width: 6vw;
  height: 6vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span class="circle bg">
    <span></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Вариант на SVG**

```html
<div style="width: 300px; margin: 30px auto;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
       viewBox="-4 -4 648 580">
    <defs>
      <mask id="cp">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
        <circle cx="325" cy="480" r="70" />
      </mask>
      <linearGradient id="lg">
        <stop stop-color="#C28F45" offset="0"/>
        <stop stop-color="#fff" offset="50%" stop-opacity="1" />
        <stop stop-color="#C28F45" offset="100%"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g>
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="600" height="440" fill="url(#lg)" mask="url(#cp)"/>
    <path d="M250,480 0,480 0,0 640,0 640,480 400,480 "fill="none" stroke="#C28F45" stroke-width="8"/>
    <circle cx="325" cy="480" r="60" fill="none" stroke="#C28F45" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
      <circle cx="325" cy="480" r="45" fill="#C28F45"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: В вопросе на кружке и рамке тоже градиент.

Comment: @Qwertiy  `stroke="url(#lg)"`

Comment: @Qwertiy  https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qeNoKv

Answer (score 0):

мб профессионалы css сделают, я попробовал пока не получается совсем, а то мне самому интересно посмотреть реализации.

```css
body {
 background: url('http://www.mariacenoura.pt/ptpictures/f/13/139206_lenovo-wallpaper.jpg');
}
.div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 10px solid hsla(0,0%,100%,.5);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #f39c12, #ADF2F7);
/* решение фон не растягивается под рамку  */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  /* стили */
 max-width: 15em;
 padding: 2em;
 margin: 2em auto 0;
 font: 30px/1.5 Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  z-index: -2;
  
}

.div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    width: 110%;
    height: 120%;
    top: -25px;
    left: -30px;
border-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 0%, #ADF2F7 100%);
border-image-slice: 1;
  
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f39c12;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 5px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.8);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  bottom: -100px;
  
}
.bg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  left: -15px;
  
  top: -15px;
  
}
.circle:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
 transform: translateY(50%);
   transform: translateX(25%);
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #f39c12, #ADF2F7);
}
.circle:before {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateX(-25%);
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f39c12, #ADF2F7);
}
```

```html
<div class="div">Пора повторить <br> мои коронные ПА.
  <div class="circle"><div class="bg"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почти не считается))